# How to install pyconcrete ? Unable to install and getting an exception

Tags: python-3.x

The below command is giving some exception while executing

```
pip install pyconcrete==0.15.1
```

Error:

```
Collecting pyconcrete
  Using cached pyconcrete-0.15.1.tar.gz (49 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Installing collected packages: pyconcrete
  DEPRECATION: pyconcrete is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for pyconcrete: started
  Running setup.py install for pyconcrete: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Running setup.py install for pyconcrete did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

latest pip(22.x) deprecate the legacy installation in pyconcrete.
you could clone the source code and install it standalone

get the pyconcrete source code

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Falldog/pyconcrete.git
```

install pyconcrete

```
$ python setup.py install
```